# only display real value from complex array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, complex-numbers, tofixed

This question is similar to one of my previous questions ([removing objects in an object in an array javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818475/removing-objects-in-an-object-in-an-array-javascript/47818994?noredirect=1#comment82641497_47818994)). However instead of having only numbers, there are also complex numbers with "NaN" as the real values. I thought this could be happening since I'm using big numbers and Mathjs, but all of my other values are already floated to ~15 decimal places. The returned array froma console.log(realPowers) looks like this in the console log:

```
0:0
1:91.51069578156118
2:183.02210760273937
3:277.73380284266796
4:376.47588381083307
5:481.85928667762994
6:599.6533611633058
7:752.8633763048005
8:Complex {re: NaN, im: -0.015021590179814361}
9:Complex {re: NaN, im: -0.029563247908981544}
10:Complex {re: NaN, im: -0.047829041780228475}
```

This is interesting since the first line of code below should return only the real values of the complex numbers. I am trying to feed these values into a for loop using the toFixed method to reduce the number of decimal places:

```
var realPowers = results.totalPower.map((x) => x && x.re ? x.re :x);

function fixPowers(realPowers) {

  var k,fixedPower,powerToFix

  for (k=0,fixedRealPowers=[]; k < realPowers.length; k++) {
    powerToFix = realPowers[k];
    fixedPower = powerToFix.toFixed(3);
    fixedRealPowers.push(fixedPower);
  }
  return fixedRealPowers
};
```

Where totalPower is the original array. But when I do that it returns an error:

```
powerToFix.toFixed is not a function
```

since toFixed cannot be used on a string (I'm assuming).

I am trying to make an array that looks like this:

```
0:0
1:91.51069578156118
2:183.02210760273937
3:277.73380284266796
4:376.47588381083307
5:481.85928667762994
6:599.6533611633058
7:752.8633763048005
8:NaN
9:NaN
10:NaN
```

Can I reduce the number of decimals for the real numbers and keep only the NaN part of the complex numbers using this same or similar method?

Comment: What do you mean by "keep only the NaN part of the complex numbers"? Could you amend your question, and add an example of what you;d like the output to be please?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `totalPower` argument to `fixPowers()`? You never use the variable inside the function.

Comment: What does `console.log(powerToFix);` show when you get that error?

Comment: I have ammended my question per your requests.

Comment: @Barmar, logging powerToFix returns the realPowers array until it reaches the first complex value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `NaN` is considered falsey in Javascript, so `x && x.re` is `falsey` for the complex numbers with `re: NaN`. It then returns `x`, which is the whole complex number. If you want to test whether a property exists, use the `hasOwnProperty()` method.

```js
function Complex(real, imag) {
  return {re: real, im: imag};
}
var results = {
  totalPower: [
    0,
    91.51069578156118,
    183.02210760273937,
    277.73380284266796,
    376.47588381083307,
    481.85928667762994,
    599.6533611633058,
    752.8633763048005,
    Complex(NaN, -0.015021590179814361),
    Complex(NaN, -0.029563247908981544),
    Complex(NaN, -0.047829041780228475)
  ]
};

var realPowers = results.totalPower.map((x) => x && x.hasOwnProperty('re') ? x.re :x);

function fixPowers() {

  var k,fixedPower,powerToFix

  for (k=0,fixedRealPowers=[]; k < realPowers.length; k++) {
    powerToFix = realPowers[k];
    fixedPower = powerToFix.toFixed(3);
    fixedRealPowers.push(fixedPower);
  }
  return fixedRealPowers
};

console.log(fixPowers());
```

Comment: Great fix. Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

```
var realPowers = results.totalPower.map((x) => x && x.re ? x.re :x);

function fixPowers(totalPower) {

  var k,fixedPower,powerToFix

  for (k=0,fixedRealPowers=[]; k < realPowers.length; k++) {
    powerToFix = realPowers[k];

    fixedPower = isNaN(powerToFix) ? powerToFix : powerToFix.toFixed(3);
    fixedRealPowers.push(fixedPower);
  }
  return fixedRealPowers
};
```